# Converting binary to base64 using openssl get openssl.exe has stopped working message

Tags: command-line, binary, openssl, base64, command-line-arguments

I am trying to convert a file containing a binary key hash to base64 using openssl. The command I am using is as follows:

```
openssl base64 -in sha.txt > debug_base64.txt
```

sha.txt holds the binary string. When I execute this in command line (in C:\openssl\bin) I get the Windows pop-up telling me openssl.exe has stopeed working. I am using openssl version 0.9.8e_X64.

How can I troubleshoot this issue? Or is there another way to convert my binary file?

Answer (score 0):

I also have this bug.
and I found that you must using [9.8k version of openssl](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list).

It very strange. I know. Especially 9.8k not work for production key and then you must use at 9.8e version of openssl...

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: Thanks for answering a question. But, please add an explanation to your code why it solves the question.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.